# meaning of 'do a lot of doors'

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from [a news podcast](https://www.npr.org/2022/03/23/1088169655/morning-news-brief).

> THOMAS HALL: I **do a lot of doors**, and I do a lot of yard signs to get
> our message out. But right now we're kind of in a holding pattern to
> see where we should be putting these signs. Obviously, we don't want
> to create further confusion to the voters.

I wonder what 'do a lot of doors' means in the above context.

My sense is that it means 'visit many houses'.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. I would understand this expression, in the context of political canvassing, to be shorthand for

> I do a lot of knocking on people's front doors

Comment: Thank you very much.